# How to share classes, with server side decorators, between server and client

Tags: node.js, angular

I have repository with server project, client project, and shared folder.

In shared folder i have for example User model.

There is all fine, until i trying to add decorators, then , angular try to compile unnecessary server libs.

My class:

```
import {ObjectType, ArgsType, Field} from "../../data-server/node_modules/type-graphql";

@ObjectType()
@ArgsType()
export class User {
    @Field()
    _id?: string;
    @Field()
    firstName: string;
    @Field()
    lastName: string;
}
```

And the angular compile error

```
ERROR in ../data-server/node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(36,13): error TS2583: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

I don't wont to use interfaces, because i wont to put them some logic, and i don't wont to create 2 same classes .
So there is another solution for that?

Comment: Dif you try create a class User without decorator (used by angular and your server) and a ServerUser class which extends User and add graphql decorators ?

Comment: I know that is solution, but i don't wont to duplicate all my models.